# Not able to understand the below pandas code

Tags: python, pandas

can anyone please explain me how the below code is working? My Question is like if y variable has only price than how the last function is able to grouby doors? I am not able to get the flow and debug the flow. Please let me know as i am very  new to this field.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('http://cdn.sundog-soft.com/Udemy/DataScience/cars.xls')
y = df['Price']
y.groupby(df.Doors).mean()
```

Comment: Tags are essential for ensuring that your question will reach the appropriate people; this is a pure `pandas` question and has nothing to do with `machine-learning`. Notice also that use of `data-science` tag is not advised (too general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('http://cdn.sundog-soft.com/Udemy/DataScience/cars.xls')
y = df['Price']
print("The Doors")
print(df.Doors)
print("The Price")
print(y)
y.groupby(df.Doors).mean()
```

Try the above code you will understand the position or the index where the "df.Doors" given 4 and the price at that index in "y" are considered as one group and mean is taken, same is for 2 doors in "df.Doors" the other group.

Answer (score 0):

It loads the popular cars dataset to the dataframe `df` and assigns  the colum price of the dataset to the variable y.

I would recommend you to get a general understanding of the data you loaded with the following commands:

```
df.info()
#shows you the range of the index as
#well as the data type of the colums
df.describe()
#shows common stats like mean or median
df.head()
#shows you the first 5 rows
```

The groupby command packs the rows (also called observations) of the cars dataframe `df` by the number of doors. And shows you the average price for cars with 2 doors or 4 doors and so on.

Check the output by adding a `print()` around the last line of code

**edit:** sorry I answered to fast, thought u asked for a general explanation of the code and not why is it working

Answer (score 0):

It works because y is a pandas series, in which the values are prices but also has the index that it had in the df. When you do `df.Doors` you get a series with different values, but the same indexes (since an index is for the whole row). By comparing the indexes, pandas can perform the group by.